# How to use MySQL Data within <a href=""></a> Tag?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am facing a problem with a WordPress website. I have a table named `wp0o_terms` I am fetching data via

```php
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM wp0o_terms" );
foreach ( $result as $print );
```

Printing as- `echo $print->name;`, where name is a field containing URL ( https://example.com ).

Actually, I want the URL within a `a tag` like `href="$print->name;"`
Everything is okay, but the link https://example.com is loading with currentpageurl/https://example.com.

I want only https://example.com which is in my table field.

`Thank you`

Comment: Can you show what a sample of the actual HTML output is? You're also sticking a `;` in your `href` field for reasons unknown.

Comment: https://evalonanalytics.com/career/job-at-transcom-limited/state.gov. I am printing only state.gov within href="state.gov" but it is generating as href="https://evalonanalytics.com/career/job-at-transcom-limited/state.gov". Without a href it is printing as state.gov

Comment: state.gov is fetching from table wp0o where name is the field name.

Comment: Define "generating". Do you mean "Is showing up as when clicked" or "is literally that in the generated source"? Remember `href="x"` will go to the current URL with `/x` slapped on the end. You *need* to specify `https://...` from the top to go to another site.

Comment: Great! It is working with https://

Comment: Every URL is the same. The URL of the last post is showing for every post. But I want the exact URL inserted for the specific post.
My table structure is *wp0o_terms*->term_id, name, name_slug where name is the URL.

Comment: Do. Not. Forget. The. Prefix. You can't just put in `state.gov` and expect it to work.

Comment: Could you please help me with this --- Every URL is the same. The URL of the last post is showing for every post. But I want the exact URL inserted for the specific post. My table structure is wp0o_terms->term_id, name, name_slug where name is the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I just got help on a similar question and the answer to yours would be to use something like

```
echo '<h3><a href ='. $print['URL'].'>'.$print['Name'].'</a></h3>';
```

Though I will say, you need to be sure you are storing the URL on a different column in MySQL or whatever database you are using. I have a column called CourseName but in order to get to that columns URL I am using CourseURL

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31533272)